# Pyinstaller - How to bundle WGET

Tags: python, curl, wget, pyinstaller

I'm using: Python 2.7 and Pyinstaller 2.1.

I'm able to successfully create a single executable with the -F argument. My script leverages wget to upload a file to a remote server. Let's just say that I need to use either wget or curl to achieve this (I know there are other modules that can accomplish this). This is done via a subprocess call. The problem that I'm having is that whatever Windows machine executes the script, wget/curl must already be installed.

Is there a way, via Pyinstaller, to include the wget binaries? So that the executable contains all the necessities to run the script and utilize wget/curl?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Why use `wget` for the upload? You can achieve everything `wget` can do with pure Python.

Comment: [PyInstaller Documentation](https://pythonhosted.org/PyInstaller/#adding-binary-files)